# Pdoc doesn't recognize Google-Style

Tags: python, documentation, google-style-guide, pdoc

I am trying to use the google-style directive with pdoc, but it doesn't work on my side.
Where am I wrong? Below is my code.
Please help me.
:)

```
    def save(a: str, b:str) -> set:
        """
            Do something

            Args:
                a (str): The first parameter.
                b (str): The second parameter.

            Returns:
                Set: The return value. If result has values then Set of string, otherwise empty set.

            """
```

OUTPUT

> Do something
>
> Args: a (str): The first parameter. b (str): The second parameter.
>
> Returns: Set: The return value. If result has values then Set of
> string, otherwise empty set.

Answer (score 3):

Did you tell pdoc to [process your docstrings as Google-style docstrings](https://pdoc.dev/docs/pdoc.html#use-numpydoc-or-google-docstrings)?

Using `pdoc --docformat google ./alf.py`, I get the following result:

[image: pdoc screenshot]